# Magento Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Foomancommon_Helper_Data' not found

Tags: magento, fatal-error

when I test my website by Google webmaster and get a score 45 and some suggestion to improve some area. I did so and my score increase.

Finally I install fooman speedster for increase my Server response time via "Filezilla". and every thing I got green. when i test my site (http://www.jrdecal.com) through Google page speed my score down at 42.

so, I uninstall fooman from my hosting file page by following your Fooman instruction. Now I have error in my admin Page.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Foomancommon_Helper_Data' not found 
in /home4/jrs/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546
```

Please give me a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be creating due helper class is  `not decleared in Foomancommon extension at config.xml`,
Then declare

```
<global>
<helpers>
<foomancommon>
<class>YourmoduleNamaspace_Foomancommon_Helper</class>
</foomancommon>
</helpers>

</global>
```

create a helper class file at app/code/(local or community)/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class YourModuleNamespace_Foomancommon_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{
}
```

If the extension was removed then there have some helper functions in your code.removed the codes `Mage::helper('foomancommon')`.

Comment: Thanks @amitBera for youe time, I have this code on config.xml                        <global>
<helpers>
<foomancommon>
<class>Foomancommon_Helper</class>
</foomancommon>
</helpers>
</global>                                                        and helper class file at app/code/community/Fooman/common/Helper/Data.php                                                       <?php
class Foomancommon_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{
}   when i remove this extension there is nothing like this code on my mage.php file. I don't want to continue with this extension.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a year, but for anybody having the same issue:

I had the same problem and fixed it by deleting:

/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/fooman_common.xml

and be sure to clear the cache by completely removing:

/var/cache/